# Groovy If with multiple conditions

Tags: jmeter

If we want to execute a thread group with 2 concurrent users only when IP Address is not in (10.0.0.1, 10.0.0.2). How can we achieve this?

I have used below condition but its not working
${__groovy(if ((org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils.getLocalHostIP()!='10.0.0.1') || (org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils.getLocalHostIP()!='10.0.0.2')) return '2' else return '0',)}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to change `||` operator to `&&` operator

```
${__groovy(if ((org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils.getLocalHostIP()!='10.10.10.1') && (org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils.getLocalHostIP()!='10.0.0.2')) return '2' else return '0',)}
```

You can also consider slightly changing syntax so it would be more readable and it would be easier to add next IPs if needed:

```
${__groovy(if (['10.0.0.1'\, '10.0.0.2'].contains(org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils.getLocalHostIP())) return '0' else return '2',)}
```

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Logical Operators](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-operators.html#_logical_operators)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)